# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm working in nextjs  and overrided _app.js inorder to show header in all pages.I have placed header in layout and used it in _app.js.in header there is search bar.on search,search result must be sent to other component from header.Api is working fine but returns below warning

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is
>   a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix,
>   cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the
>   componentWillUnmount method.

constant.js

```
export var searchKey = "";
export const setSearchKey = (value) => {
    searchKey = value;
}
export const getSearchKey = (value) => {
    return searchKey;
}
```

header.js

```
import * as searchConst from '../../static/constants/constants';

class HeaderComponent extends Component {
    state = {
        authType: true
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', this.routeChangeHandler);
    }

    routeChangeHandler(url) {
        url === '/appUser' ? this.setState({authType: true}) : this.setState({authType: false})
    }

    onSearch(event) {

        ApiService.onSearchUsers(0, this.state.authType, document.getElementById('search-input').value).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            searchConst.setSearchKey(document.getElementById('search-input').value); //if i remove this line then there is no warning

            this.props.parentCallBack(userdata);

        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="search-col">
                <Input id="search-input" className="text-box" placeholder="Enter name or Email.."
                       onKeyDown={($event) => this.onSearch($event)}
                       prefix={<Icon type="search" onClick={() => this.onSearch}></Icon>}></Input>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning happens because you're setting the state on component mount. If for some reason the component gets unmounted before the state is updated, you'll get the warning. One way to avoid the warning is to set `mounted` state to false in the `componentWillUnmount` and check against it before modifying the state:

```
  state = {
    authType: true,
    mounted: true
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', this.routeChangeHandler);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    setState({
      mounted: false
    });
  }

  routeChangeHandler(url) {
    if (mounted) {
      this.setState({
        authType: url === '/appUser'
      })
    }
  }
```